# VSTO application deployment error

Tags: wpf, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I am facing VSTO error when I am trying to install the application using click once installer. I have tried on Windows XP machine and also on Windows 7 machine.
Exact error when opening the application on client machine is

> “The following Microsoft solution cannot be loaded because a compatible version of the .NET Framework is not Installed: myApplicationName.vsto”

The application is VSTO app in C# with WPF tab embedded in Excel application (Framework 4).
The framework the application is developed on is already installed on the client machine.
I did not find any solution in this thread; any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like either the client machine doesn't have .NET 4 installed, or your VSTO requires the full framework but the client machine has only the client profile framework.

Comment: What version of Office is on the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I believe this is a problem with the VSTO 2010 installer included with your application.

I went and downloaded the latest version from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217), installed it, retried my installer and then everything worked.